# C# I need to allow The First thread to reach a certian point prevents other threads from continuing

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have multithreads working on the same threadsafe function. After X amount of iterations, The first thread to reach firstThread(), will execute firstThread() and prevent the other threads from continuing until thread is finished with firstThread(). Only the first thread to reach firstThread() will execute the others will not. Kind of like a race first one to the finish line is the winner. After firstThread() is completed all threads continue until limit is reached again. Does anyone have any ideas one best way to accomplish this, Would be greatly appreciated.

```
    private void ThreadBrain()
    {
        Thread[] tList = new Thread[ThreadCount];
        sw.Start();

        for (int i = 0; i < tList.Length; i++)
        {
            tList[i] = new Thread(ThProc);
            tList[i].Start();
        }

        foreach (Thread t in tList)
            if (t != null) t.Join();





    }
    private void ThProc()
    {

            doWork();



    }
   private void firstThread()
   {
    //do some work
  loopCount=0;
  }

    private void doWork()
    {
//do some work
    loopCount++;
     //first thread to reach this point calls firstThread() and prevent other threads from continuing until current thread completes firstThread()
     If(loopCount>=loopLimit)firstThread()
}
```

Comment: In the `if (t != null) t.Join();`, the `if` part is useless. In C# if a `new` fail it will throw an exception. There is no silent failure of `new`.

Answer (score 1):

This will do it. Only the first thread to enter will change `OnlyFirst` from 0 to 1 and receive 0 from the `Interlocked.CompareExchange`. The other threads will fail and receive 1 from `Interlocked.CompareExchange` and then `return`.

```
private int OnlyFirst = 0;

private void doWork()
{
    if (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref OnlyFirst, 1, 0) != 0)
    {
        return;
    }
```

Comment: I assume that the OP wants a synchronization barrier too.

Comment: @Douglas It would be useless... The first thread to enter will see *its* memory "coherently", while the other threads haven't finished, so there is no guarantee they are in a coherent state from the POV of the first thread.

Comment: I meant "[synchronization barrier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barrier_%28computer_science%29)", not "memory barrier". However, upon re-reading the question, I don't think a barrier is what they're requesting; rather, they just need a critical section.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Flag that will only be "true" for the first thread to enter the method.
private bool isFirstThread = true;

// The "Synchronized" option ensures that only one thread can execute the method
// at a time, with the others getting temporarily blocked.
[MethodImplOptions.Synchronized]
private void firstThread()
{
    if (isFirstThread)
    {
        //do some work
        loopCount=0;

        isFirstThread = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Depending on what the OP wants, you could use the `Monitor.TryLock`, so that the other threads can go to die.

Comment: I've rolled back to my first answer (which doesn't use `Monitor` explicitly).